# What is the best way to read a USB device using Java?

Tags: java, usb

I want to write an app that is connected to a robotic arm, which is connected by USB to my PC. I want to use Java.

So far, I haven't found a reliable way to make this connection happen.

Can I get some advice on what to use and how to use it?

Comment: Have you looked into using [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/)?

Comment: I did, but I get this dll error Exception in thread "main" org.usb4java.LoaderException: Native library not found in classpath: /org/usb4java/win32-x86-64/libusb4java.dll

Comment: What operating system are you using? The [documentation](http://usb4java.org/nativelibs.html#Unsupported_platforms) says you might get that if your system is not supported by usb4java

Comment: @xtratic i'm on win10

Comment: Are you not using a dependency manager, such as maven, to include the usb4java dependency? Also check what's on your runtime classpath.

Comment: Im using maven, but still cant read the device with usb4java, you have a code example for me ?

Comment: I've posted an example, if it works for you then please accept it as the answer.

Comment: "Native library not found in classpath" could indicate that you haven't installed libusb or the libusb dll is not on the PATH. It is not bundled with usb4java.

Comment: Does your robotic arm use a custom USB protocol? Or does it use a virtual serial port? In the latter case, usb4java won't help.

Comment: It does, I made this python code that works fine, also, there is bluetooth. @Codo

Comment: How to add the libusb dll btw ? @Codo

Comment: Download the binaries from https://libusb.info/, extract libusb-1.0.dll from VS2015-x64\dll and put it into a directory that's listed in PATH. Possibly you can also put the dll into your project and load it dynamically from Java. But I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me on win32-x86-64:

```java
import org.usb4java.*;
    
public class SO72998852 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int status = LibUsb.init(null);
        try {
            if (status != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize libusb.", status);
            }
            DeviceList list = new DeviceList();
            try {
                status = LibUsb.getDeviceList(null, list);
                if (status < 0) {
                    throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", status);
                }
                for (Device device : list) {
                    DeviceDescriptor descriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
                    status = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, descriptor);
                    if (status != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to read device descriptor", status);
                    }
                    System.out.println(descriptor);
                }
            } finally {
                LibUsb.freeDeviceList(list, true);
            }
        } finally {
            LibUsb.exit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

---

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.usb4java/usb4java-javax -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.usb4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>usb4java-javax</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, ill try it out later today and give you some feedback, whats your JDK version ?

Comment: I ran with Java 8